# T-SQL - passing column to subquery for filtering

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-order-by

I have the need to pass a column to a subquery for filtering, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I understand that if my subquery were to return a single column, then I could re-arrange my query and it would work, but I need the subquery to return 3 columns.

Here is my query so far and its complaining about th:

```
 where c.location.STDistance(l.location) is not null
 order by c.Location.STDistance(l.location)
```

with

> The multi-part identifier "l.location" could not be bound.

```
select
    l.*, city.*
from  
    listings l, 
    (select top 1 c.UnicodeName, c.name, r.code as region, cn.code as country 
     from cities c
     inner join regions r on r.regionid = c.regionid
     inner join Countries cn on cn.CountryId = r.countryid
     where c.location.STDistance(l.location) is not null
     order by c.Location.STDistance(l.location)) as city
```

Actual plan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkiRk-74P

Indexes on cities and listings

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [256_HHHH] ON [dbo].[Listings]
(
    [Location]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = HIGH,LEVEL_3 = HIGH,LEVEL_4 = HIGH), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 256, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [16_HHHH] ON [dbo].[Listings]
(
    [Location]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = HIGH,LEVEL_2 = HIGH,LEVEL_3 = HIGH,LEVEL_4 = HIGH), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: The subquery you have aliased as `city` almost feels like it belongs in the _select_ clause.

Comment: I tried that but once its in the select it complains that the subquery must only return one column, where as mine returns 3 (city.*)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a lateral join, where the joined subquery uses columns from the `listing` table. This fails because of the comma in the `from` clause: some databases do recognize such implicit lateral joins, but not SQL Server.

You have to be explicit about the join type (which is best practice anyway): use `cross apply`.

```
select l.*, city.*
from  listings l
cross apply (
     select  top (1)  c.UnicodeName, c.name, r.code as region, cn.code as country from cities c
     inner join regions r on r.regionid = c.regionid
     inner join Countries cn on cn.CountryId = r.countryid
     where c.location.STDistance(l.location) is not null
     order by c.Location.STDistance(l.location) 
 ) as city
```

Comment: That worked but its very slow, 53 seconds to do 12k listings.  I have attached the execution plan but i dont know what I can do to improve it.  I have 2 spatial indexes on both listing and city tables (edited the main post with those as well)